# Android: How to make the navigation like this?

Tags: android

May I ask how to make the navigation menu like Facebook Apps? Is it listview? Thanks.

[image: facebook help page]

Comment: Would you please clarify your question..it looks like a list view..whats is your problem exactly?

Comment: Sorry. I am new in developing Android. I want to make the navigation like above images. May I know how can I do that? Or Can you provide some keywords for me to google. I have no idea about that.

Comment: If you are talking about the menu drawer, you can use this lib https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer

Comment: Thank you brother. I will explorer it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try this [**Android facebook style slide**](https://github.com/gitgrimbo/android-sliding-menu-demo) example project

Comment: Opps. I find the keyword "sliding menu" from your link. Thank you so much. It is very helpful!=]